# Using RcppArmadillo each_col with lambda function?

Tags: r, rcpp

According to the Armadillo website, you can pass in a lambda function into `.each_col`, such as

`X.each_col( [](vec& a){ a.print(); } );`

The following Rcpp seems to have an error though, reporting "Expected Expression"

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec colCumSum(const arma::mat& X) {
  return X.each_col( [](const arma::vec& b){ b.cumsum(); } );  
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually have to tell R to use C++11 in order to have lambda support.  The magic line is `[[Rcpp::plugins("cpp11")]]` which makes it all work:

But once I do that I get issues on the `cumsum()`.  You also had too many `const` in there.

So here is a simpler version which *does* work with another `lambda` from the documentation -- which just prints.  I also turned to `ivec` and `imat` for consistency:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::plugins("cpp11")]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::ivec colCumSum(arma::imat& X) {
  X.each_col( [](arma::ivec& a){ a.print(); } );
  return X.col(0);
}

/*** R
M <- matrix(1:16, 4, 4)
colCumSum(M)
*/
```

When you source this, it builds and runs.  You will need to work out the lambda use case for the reduction that `cumsum()` does.

```
> sourceCpp("/tmp/foo.cpp")

> M <- matrix(1:16, 4, 4)

> colCumSum(M)
        1
        2
        3
        4
        5
        6
        7
        8
         9
        10
        11
        12
        13
        14
        15
        16
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    3
[4,]    4
>
```

Comment: Thanks! It turns out the proper way to call cumsum is ```cumsum(b)```. Also, digging further Armadillo already had a way to do cumsum per column using ```cumsum(X, 0)```

Comment: You could still use a lambda for cumsum of log or some other transformation.  But thanks for the follow-up!